# Slow bash under WSL

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a Windows 10 system with WSL v2 Ubuntu enabled. If I run bash from Windows to call a programm installed on Linux, it is very slow (500-800ms) for even a trivial command.

I used Measure-Command in PowerShell to time it:

```
PS C:\Users\thoma\Desktop> Measure-Command { bash -c "echo Hello" }

...
TotalMilliseconds : 655,8447
```

In comparision cmd takes a fraction:

```
PS C:\Users\thoma\Desktop> Measure-Command { cmd /c echo Hello }

...
TotalMilliseconds : 17,5062
```

Any ideas why this is so slow? I deactivated any anti virus software.

Comment: For a comparable result you should not call bash from within a PowerShell. Calling cmd.exe is like a local phone call and calling something from WSL is like a far call to a different continent.

Comment: That makes sense, but I feel that it used to be much quicker. Could anyone else execute these two calls and share their results?

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen an increase in the startup time recently, did anything change in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (or any other startup config)?

Using `bash` to start up WSL is a bit outdated, so I'm going to use the `wsl` command for the purposes of the following examples.  It's more flexible, at the very least.

You don't mention in your question whether or not WSL was running when you executed your one-and-only `Measure-Command` against it.  Let's do it several times, with a cold start and a warm start:

First, I terminate the WSL instance with `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` and confirm it is stopped with `wsl -l -v`.

Then, `Measure-Command { wsl -e bash -noprofile -norc -c "echo Hello" }`.  This keeps `bash` from reading the startup config.

My results on a fresh start of WSL were consistently around 280ms.  A second run with WSL already running was between 96ms-100ms.

Your `cmd` example, for me, was around 17ms, with one outlier being 34ms.  Of course, CMD is pretty much always loaded in Windows, since it's used for so much.  So there's never (to my knowledge) any "cold startup time" for it.

Also, for reference, from *within* WSL, I used `hyperfine` to test the same (and converse):

```
> hyperfine 'bash -noprofile -norc -c "echo Hello"'
Benchmark #1: bash -noprofile -norc -c "echo Hello"
  Time (mean ± σ):       1.2 ms ±   0.6 ms    [User: 1.2 ms, System: 0.1 ms]
  Range (min … max):     0.8 ms …   5.2 ms    1660 runs
```

```
> hyperfine 'powershell.exe -NoProfile -c "echo Hello"'
Benchmark #1: powershell.exe -NoProfile -c "echo Hello"
  Time (mean ± σ):     263.5 ms ±   6.6 ms    [User: 5.6 ms, System: 0.3 ms]
  Range (min … max):   256.6 ms … 279.5 ms    11 runs
```

```
> hyperfine 'cmd.exe -c "echo Hello"'
Benchmark #1: cmd.exe -c "echo Hello"
  Time (mean ± σ):      27.9 ms ±   2.4 ms    [User: 3.6 ms, System: 0.4 ms]
  Range (min … max):    23.7 ms …  34.0 ms    98 runs
```

```
> hyperfine 'pwsh.exe -NoProfile -c "echo Hello"'
Benchmark #1: pwsh.exe -NoProfile -c "echo Hello"
  Time (mean ± σ):     461.1 ms ±   7.7 ms    [User: 5.6 ms, System: 1.4 ms]
  Range (min … max):   453.9 ms … 476.5 ms    10 runs
```